# Ruby using User input as an integer

Tags: ruby, input

I am getting the error, square.rb:9:in `*': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
    from square.rb:9:in`'.

I am sure it is an easy fix, I am just very new to ruby.

```
    cnt = 0

    puts "Enter a number: "
    wid = gets.chomp


    print '*' * wid
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use `to_i` to convert to integer:

```
value = wid.to_i
```